# How do I make vim open a browsed file location in the current window even if it's open elsewhere?

Tags: vim

Suppose I browse to a directory in vim by typing `:e some/dir/`. Vim will take me to a list of directories and files.

If I now select `some.file` it will either

1. Open the file if it is not already open, or
2. Take me to the tab/window where the file is already open

How do I disable the 2nd option, so that vim will open the file in that window even if it is already open elsewhere? I can force this behaviour manually by typing `:e some/dir/some.file` but how do I make it happen when I select the file?

I am running `vim 7.4`

Comment: I don't see that behavior; does it help if you `:set switchbuf=`?

Comment: NERDTree makes it work the way you expect. (Even if you don't open it)